# When I try to update row in sqlite nothing happens in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

When I try to update row in database nothing happens, what I am doing wrong?

```
private void buttonUpdate_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myDB.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        Airplane airplane = new Airplane()
        {
            SearchId = planeEntry.Text + airlineEntry.Text + liveryEntry.Text + registrationEntry.Text + airportEntry.Text + commentEntry.Text,
            Plane = planeEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
            Airline = airlineEntry.Text,
            Livery = liveryEntry.Text,
            Registration = registrationEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
            Airport = airportEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
            Comment = commentEntry.Text
        };
        db.Update(airplane);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"?  What do you expect to happen?  If you are trying to update an existing row, what is the PK?

Comment: I change for example Airline, but when I look it is same like before. How is using PK here?

Comment: Update requires the PK of the table to be set in order to work.  Are you setting the PK?  Generally when you update, you read the row from the table, change the values, and then save it again.  But you are creating a new object, which makes me think you are not setting the PK correctly.

Comment: I am using PK just on Import `Id = (maxPK == null ? 1 : maxPK.Id + 1)`, So how do I update PK here?

Comment: if you want to update an existing row, the data you save must have the **same PK** as the row that is **already in the database**.  This is just a basic db concept.

Comment: So i need to set Id =1 if it was id =1?

Comment: Yes.  How can it update the existing row if it doesn't know what the ID is?

Comment: It works thanks, you have true, do you want write good answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update an existing row, the DB has to know which Row you are updating.  You do this by setting the Primary Key

you are creating a new `Airplane` object, but not setting it's PK (ID), so the db update will fail because the DB does not know which row to update

```
    Airplane airplane = new Airplane()
    {
        SearchId = planeEntry.Text + airlineEntry.Text + liveryEntry.Text + registrationEntry.Text + airportEntry.Text + commentEntry.Text,
        Plane = planeEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
        Airline = airlineEntry.Text,
        Livery = liveryEntry.Text,
        Registration = registrationEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
        Airport = airportEntry.Text.ToUpper(),
        Comment = commentEntry.Text
    };
```